# How to log data in files in Play framework?

Tags: java, logging, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a Play server (Play framework 2.3) implemented in Java. I want to keep logs of API calls in files limiting the maximum number of files and maximum size of each file. I have the below `application-logger.xml` file

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/home/ajay/projects/application.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- Daily rollover with compression -->
        <fileNamePattern>application-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 30 days worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ} - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ACCESS_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/home/ajay/projects/access.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover with compression -->
        <fileNamePattern>access-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 1 week worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ} %message%n</pattern>
        <!-- this quadruples logging throughput -->
        <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- additivity=false ensures access log data only goes to the access log -->
<logger name="access" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ACCESS_FILE" />
</logger>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
```

which I have taken from [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsLogger). **I do not fully understand the above configuration**. I use the following lines to log into `access.log` file

```
import play.Logger;

// log in the access.log file
final Logger.ALogger accessLogger = Logger.of("access");
accessLogger.info("Logging api call from the client");
```

However, it doesn't work. The `access.log` file is empty while all logging goes to `application.log` file. I have commented out all logger settings in `application.conf`. When I looked into the file `Logger.class`, I found this line

```
private static final ALogger logger = of("application");
```

Is this the reason why it's not working? Please suggest how do I fix it.

Comment: What happens if you use log4j instead? `import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; /* (...) */ LoggerFactory.getLogger("access").error("Just a test");`

Comment: @Salem I tried it but doesn't seem to work. All logs get written to `application.log` file only.

Comment: It could be that you are not seeing the logs "immediately" as the "immediateFlush" property is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

Try this appender:

```
 <appender name="CUSTOM" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${application.home}/logs/agent.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${application.home}/logs/old/myLog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %M  %logger{0} %message%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

In the file name pattern put the application home path.

Answer (score 0):

`immediateFlush` property of your appender is set to false, so you don't see any changes in access.log file immediately. Just remove

```
<immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
```

line from your configuration xml.

[From the logback documentation:](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/encoders.html#immediateFlush) Immediate flushing of the output stream ensures that logging events are immediately written to disk and will not be lost in case your application exits without properly closing appenders.